# How can I attach a visio default data graphic to a shape

Tags: visio

I have an OBDC datasource in Visio.  I need to setup a specific data graphic to a shape, so whenever a shape is used that datagraphic is used.  If this is built into visio i apologize, but im not quite sure where to get started.

Seems like such a simple problem to fix. :(

Comment: It sounds like you want a data graphic to be applied to a shape automatically as soon as you drop the shape, which would imply the shape somehow has data in it when you drop the shape.  How are you accomplishing that?

Comment: We have a linked OBDC data source, 1 mysql, and 1 Microsoft SQL server the data comes from.  Servers run LabTech/ConnectWise RMM.

Comment: But yeah, that it exactly what i want, drag and drop, so i can just link the data and it knows what data graphic by the shape used.  That way we can have 1 data graphic for a router, workstation, server, sonicwall, voip, ect..